# iOS application gets EXC_BAD_ACCESS at same memory address but with different causes

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am building an iOS application. It's using a C++ library which runs alongside (crowd simulation lib, which determines positions of many agents) a cocos2d game.

After I added some more animations and extra bells and whistles the app crashes after about 6-30 seconds, with errors like:
tiny_malloc_from_free_list
tiny_free_list_remove_ptr

The thing is, it ALWAYS happens at the same memory address 0x1000. But I can replicate the error on two different devices exactly, so it's not the memory itself which is bad.

I'm not expecting a complete answer, but some pointers to where I should start looking would be very nice :) thank you!

EDIT: I removed the c++ lib completely, but the error still persists. I will update once I have gotten closer.

EDIT: The problem was in the Cocos2d v. 2 display stats adding and removing pointers. Thank you for all of your help! one of the texture enum vals was 1<<12 and was used as a pointer... I stopped using the display stats. :) thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your backtrace doesn't immediately show the problem...

Sounds like it could be a deference of a nil "object", where the code is attempting to reference *(p + 0x1000). Note that 0x1000 is probably the VM page size.

In situations like this I turn on zombies and guard malloc to see if I can catch the problem as it happens.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! - I have turned on guard malloc on the sim, but I can't make it crahs on the sim, only on the device. Turning on zombies doesn't give me any information. And still, the crashes are different in nature but all refer to the same memory address. I will have a look for the nil "object" in the lib.

Comment: The backtrace is usually just one step and refers to very different things each time.

Answer (score 1):

With an address like that, I would suspect int-to-pointer conversion somewhere. What is that, 4096? I might search the library for a constant with that value (perhaps achieved via bit-shifting 1<<12), and see if I could find code using that constant in strange ways.

Comment: No constants with 4096 (or ways of getting to that number, no bit shifting at all). I'm looking for the int to pointer conversion, but a lot of lines to look through :) - thank you for the reply!

Comment: 4096 is the page size.  It's likely a constant internal to the malloc library.